# Odd Javascript behavior for array of strings

Tags: javascript

Someone pointed this weird array result in JavaScript and I was hoping someone could explain why this happens.

If I have an array like so:

```
var arr = ["10", "10", "10", "10"];
```

And I try to map those "10"'s to integers like so:

```
arr.map(parseInt);
```

The result will be an array with the values: [10, NaN, 2, 3] (I ran all of this code in Chrome's console)

I expected the result to be: [10, 10, 10, 10]

I understand that JavaScript can parse integers from string into different numbering systems, like binary, which I think explains where the 2 and 3 three are coming from, kind of. But why would parseInt change to parsing them in different bases? Could someone please explain why this is the result I get?

Comment: In other words,  `parseint("10", 0) = 10, parseint("10", 1) = NaN , parseint("10", 2) = 2 , parseint("10", 3) = 3  ` It was a simple misunderstanding of the functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) accepts a callback which takes 3 arguments:

1. The current element
2. The index of the element
3. The array that this function was called on

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) takes up to two arguments:

1. The string to parse
2. (Optional) The radix i.e. the base of the number.

So in passing `parseInt` to `map`, you essentially get the following calls:

```
parseInt(arr[0], 0); // if 0, same as default
parseInt(arr[1], 1); // Parse as base 1
parseInt(arr[2], 2); // Parse as base 2 or binary
parseInt(arr[3], 3); // Parse as base 3
```

An easier and more effective way of accomplishing what you're trying is to use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number):

```js
var arr = ["10", "10", "10", "10", "23", "74"];
console.log(arr.map(Number));
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the man page on [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), it takes two parameters.  A value and a radix.

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) sends three parameters: `currentValue, index, array`

Use `Number` instead

```
["10", "20"].map(Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

it works this way :

```
 var arr = ["10", "10", "10", "10"];
 var newArr = arr.map(function(num){
    return parseInt(num);
 });

 console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You see that weird behaviour because the actual Parseint considers second value as radix

ParseInt syntax:
parseInt(string, radix);

This behaviour is explained in developer.mozilla.org

For reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map